# Tkinter paragraphs

Tags: python, tkinter, paragraph

This shows what I have and want:

[image: image showing tkinter layout desired]

So yeah as you can see I want a paragraph exactly where the red line is. The buttons should appear beneath the 2 text boxes.

Current bit of code:

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Taschenrechner")

window.label_zahl1 = Label(window, text = 'Zahl 1:', anchor = W, justify = LEFT)
window.label_zahl1.pack(side=LEFT)
window.entry_zahl1 = Entry()
window.entry_zahl1.pack(side=LEFT)

window.label = Label(window, text = '\n')
window.label.pack(side=LEFT)

window.label_zahl2 = Label(window, text = 'Zahl 2:')
window.label_zahl2.pack(side=LEFT)
window.entry_zahl2 = Entry()
window.entry_zahl2.pack(side=LEFT)

window.button_plus = Button(window, text = "+")
window.button_plus.pack(side=LEFT)

window.button_minus = Button(window, text = "-")
window.button_minus.pack(side=LEFT)

window.button_divi = Button(window, text = "/")
window.button_divi.pack(side=RIGHT)

window.button_mal = Button(window, text = "*")
window.button_mal.pack(side=RIGHT)

window.ausgabe = Label(master = window, text = "")                     
window.ausgabe.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a paragraph"? Tkinter has no such concept. Are you simply asking how to line up the buttons under the Entry widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular problem, the easy solution is to use `grid` which will allow to specify a row and column for each widget.

Another simple solution is to use to separate frames. Put the labels and entries in one, and use `pack` as you are doing now. Then, in a second frame put h buttons, again using `pack` in a similar fashion. Finally, use `pack` to put the first frame on top, then use `pack` again to place the second frame below the first.